# PHP проверка имени

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

```
preg_match("#^[aA-zZ0-9\-_]+$#",$fullName
```

вопрос как добавить сюда русские символы и украинские,потому что получается как:можно вводить англ буквы, пробел, подчеркивание, дефис, а как добавить еще туда другие символы.

И объясните как вы это делайте, немного не понятно.

И еще есть один вопрос.

Есть же функция mail(), так вот когда я отправляю письмо на гугл почту, оно якобы приходит от скажем "X@gmail.com", а как сделать чтобы отправителем указывался постоянно один и тот же мэйл "Y@gmail.com".

Поскольку google выдает следующие: "Возможно, это письмо не было отправлено с адреса X@gmail.com  Подробнее...  Сообщить о фишинге"

Comment: вопрос про письма вынесите в отдельно, один пост = один вопрос

Comment: А почему бы не пойти от принципа KISS? Если у вас разрешены только буквы и цифры, воспользуйтесь простым шаблоном: `[\w\d]+`. Что к какому алфавиту оно само разберётся.

Comment: @PinkTux, `\d` - это часть `\w`.

Answer (score 1):

> как добавить сюда русские символы и украинские,потому что получается
>   как:можно вводить англ буквы, пробел, подчеркивание, дефис, а как
>   добавить еще туда другие символы.

Давайте исходить из [KISS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF)) (сделай это проще, так-то). Тримнули ввод (удалили начальные/конечные пробелы, не забываем про это), а потом:

```
/^[\w]+$/
```

Так сгодится? Ну и про модификатор `u` не забывайте.

Впрочем, при таком подходе не совсем понятно, зачем вам вообще эта проверка. Или вам нужно другое: отсечь что-то, что не входит в конкретный алфавит?

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте модификатор u:
    preg_match("#^[а-яёa-z0-9-_]{3,20}$#iu",$fullName)
Совсем забыл, надо же добавить и русские символы

Comment: к сожалению не работает

Comment: Приведите примеры имён, на которых не работает.

Comment: @PinkTux, думаю, украинские с буквами типа `ҐґЄєЇї`. Возможно, ещё какие-то косяки в связи с тем, что алфавит идёт не подряд.

Answer (score 0):

В квадратных скобках вашего выражения перечисляется символы которые необходимо найти, сейчас правило найдет все маленькие и большие буквы английского алфавита, цифры от 0 до 9, тире и знак подчеркивания. По аналогии вы можете добавить русские буквы - `аА-яЯ`, они же будут и для украинского алфавита, плюс необходимо добавить буквы которые являются специфическими - `ЁёІіЇїЄєҐґ`. В итоге вы получите нечто вроде:

```
preg_match("#^[aA-zZаА-яЯЁёІіЇїЄєҐґ0-9\-_]+$#",$fullName);
```

Как правильно написал Pink Tux, можно заменить все перечисления символов, на метасимвол `\w` он ищет "буквенный или цифровой символ или знак подчёркивания", и добавить флаг u. В итоге получится:

```
preg_match("#^[\w\-]+$#u",$fullName);
```

Comment: Спасибо, а какая должна быть кодировка в php файле ?

Comment: должнв быть utf8 без BOM